# Object of type date is not JSON Serializable

Tags: python, django

I have a table in MySQL with name, period, indicator, value as the column names. Period stores date. I am trying to get the object from django using the following code

```
def get_table(request):

    tab = list(table.objects.values('name', 'period' , 'indicator', 'value'))
    json_data = json.dumps(tab)

    return HttpResponse(json_data)
```

I receive an error saying date is not JSON Serializable. How do I convert it to string before getting the object? Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: can you please put your data in here so we will see how the date is show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try [django serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/):

```
from django.core import serializers

fields = ['name', 'period' , 'indicator', 'value']
qs = table.objects.all()
json_data = serializers.serialize('json', qs, fields=fields)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: glad to help you)

Comment: I am getting `'datetime.date' object has no attribute '_meta'`

Comment: try to generate full question, now i have no any django instance to test any solution